# Simple cycles texture node on a plane

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor, compositing-nodes

## Setup

Here's what I tried:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>n</kbd> to create a new (empty) blend
2. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm
3. <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete cube
4. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm
5. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd> **>> Mesh >> Plane** to add a new plane
6. Right-click on the lamp
7. <kbd>Del</kbd> to delete the light
8. <kbd>Enter</kbd> to confirm
9. Select **Cycles Render** to use Cycles
10. Right-click on the plane
11. Open the Materials panel
12. Assign the existing material **Material** to the plane
13. Select **Use Nodes** on the material
14. Switch to the Compositor
15. Select the Texture node editor
16. Check **Use Nodes**
17. <kbd>F12</kbd> to render

This produces:

[image: No Checkerboard]

## Question

What steps are missing to render the checkerboard on the plane using Blender v2.74 (or greater)?

## Notes

I tried to UV unwrap the plane as follows:

1. <kbd>Numpad 7</kbd> to switch to top view
2. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter Edit mode
3. Switch to Edge select mode
4. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>e</kbd> to **Mark seam**
5. <kbd>u</kbd> **>> Unwrap** to unwrap the plane
6. <kbd>Tab</kbd> to enter Object mode
7. <kbd>F12</kbd> to render

No change.

I also added an emissive plane above the original plane. This brightened the original plane, as expected, but no checkerboard appeared:

[image: No Checkerboard 2]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The part you are missing is creating a material, assigning a shader to it and  using your texture as color.

[image]

This will create a node setup on for the material>

[image]

Adding a mapping node will allow you to control size and placement of the texture:

[image]

Comment: @DaveJarvis Use an *image texture* node.